# Help with sorting results from database (JOIN?) in php

Tags: php, sorting, left-join

Im upgrading my forum a bit, and want to change the way the topics is listed.

My topics is stored in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_emner` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type_forum` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    `gjengid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sticky` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `emne` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `innlegg` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `brukerid_starter` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `startet_dato` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `antall_lest` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `antall_svar` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `type_forum` (`type_forum`),
    INDEX `gjengid` (`gjengid`),
    INDEX `sticky` (`sticky`),
    INDEX `brukerid_starter` (`brukerid_starter`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

Answers to topics is stored in this table (emneid equals id in the forum_emner table):

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_svar` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `emneid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `brukerid_av` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `innlegg` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `dato` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `emneid` (`emneid`),
    INDEX `brukerid_av` (`brukerid_av`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

dato is when the answer was posted (time() in php).

What i want: I want to sort the topics after the field, dato in forum_svar. The topic with the newest answer is on the top, and so on. But if a topic is created after the top topics last answer this topic should be on the top (how a forum actually works).

I've tried myself, but its not working as it should.

```
SELECT *, `forum_emner`.id AS UnikTradID FROM `forum_emner` 
LEFT JOIN `forum_svar` ON (`forum_emner`.id = `forum_svar`.emneid) 
WHERE `forum_emner`.type_forum = :type AND `forum_emner`.sticky = 0 
ORDER BY `forum_svar`.dato DESC LIMIT :p1, :p2
```

Any help? :)

Comment: I suggest you don't store timestamp as a number in mysql database. Use  [mysql timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

A side note: you should use `AS` as I do bellow to make the query look more readable.
And you shouldn't keep your MySQL field names in something other than English. What if you hire someone not speaking your language? :)

The first thing to do is to get the newest thread ids. 
We can do that with such query:

```
SELECT MAX(fs.id) AS LastThreadId FROM forum_svar AS fs GROUP BY fs.emneid ORDER BY LastThreadId
```

Now we need to join this result set with the threads to get full thread information.
So we do it like this by putting the first query as a subquery here:

```
SELECT fs.* FROM forum_svar AS fs LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(fs.id) AS LastThreadId FROM forum_svar AS fs GROUP BY fs.emneid ORDER BY LastThreadId DESC) n ON (n.LastThreadId = fs.id) WHERE n.LastThreadId IS NOT NULL
```

This will now get you the newest threads. Enjoy! :)
P.S. Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked out!

Comment: No it doesnt.

If the topics have any answears it prints out that many times (if a topic has 1 answer, it prints the topic 2 times on the list of topics, topics that dosent have answear prints out once, but at the bottom.).

Comment: What about now? Try the query i have here, i edited it. Oh and instead of using `*` you should specify what fields exactly you need in return rather than having all the fields..

Comment: Thanks! Its almost working now. But it just sorts the topics from the FIRST answer in each topic. It should short after the last answer in the topic. Can you help with that? :)

Comment: Its not working :P Just added "last_atctive" column to the topic table, and sort it after that. Thanks for the help anyway! :)

Comment: What's exactly not working? I could mistype something cause I had to rewrite my query to fit your table structure..